# how can i access nested json data in angular2

Tags: json, angular

this is my app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
  {{test | json}}

  <div ngFor='let test of tests' style='border: solid 1px'>
    <div>
      <P>
        writer: {{test.A.B.C.D.writerid}} <br>
        content:{{test}}<br>
        write_date:{{test}}</P>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
})

public test: any[] = [
 {
   'A': {
     'B': [{
       'C': {
         'D': [{
           'content': 'content_test1',
           'writedt': '2017-02-08 00:00:00',
           'writerid': 'writerid_test1'
          }, {
           'content': 'content_test2',
           'writedt': '2017-02-08 00:00:00',
           'writerid': 'writerid_test1'
          }, {
            'content': 'content_test3',
            'writedt': '2017-02-08 00:00:00',
            'writerid': 'writerid_test2'
         },  {
           'content': 'content_test4',
           'writedt': '2017-02-08 00:00:00',
           'writerid': 'writerid_test2'
         }]
       }
     }]
   }
 }
];
```

test.A.B.C.D.writerid is not working
error:Cannot read property 'B' of undefined
i don't understand why error is not A but B
how can i access D's content or writedt or writerid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I assume you have some typos in your template (e.g `ngFor`), and that the array is actually called `tests` but let's disregard that.

I guess you want to iterate through the array of `D`. ***Without making any changes to your structure of your data, you can do it with nested `*ngFor`:s.***

So first your array should be named `tests`, not `test`. And how to access the most inner array, we'll first iterate the `tests` array, after that iterate through array `B` and lastly the innermost array `D`. 
So your template would look like this:

```html
  <div *ngFor="let test of tests">
    <div *ngFor="let x of test.A.B">
      <div *ngFor="let y of x.C.D; let i = index"> <h4>Content {{i+1}}</h4>
        {{y.content}}
        {{y.writedt | date}}
        {{y.writerid}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/byyna1nlJKrwu2KEfZGB?p=preview)

Comment: thanks! it works!
when i get json data from constructor like
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    _http.get(this.API_URI).subscribe(result => {
     this.tests = result.json();
    });
  }

Comment: it got error : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
how can i use http data like A.B.C.D.content

Comment: Well how does your JSON look like? Seems JSON is constructed differently (or there is some async problem). Could you paste the JSON response to your question?

Comment: {
 "hits": {
  "hits": [{
   "_source": {
    "json_comments": [{
     "content": "\u314b\u314b\u314b\u314b - DCW",
     "writedt": "2016-02-08 17:05:48",
     "writerid": "morefico3042"
    }, {
     "content": "\uc800\ubc88\uc5d0 \ub3d9\uc7a5A\uc758 \ubcbd\uc744 \uc2e4\uac10\ud558\uc2dc\uace0\ub3c4 \ub3c4\uc804\ud558\uc2dc\ub294? \u3161\u3161",
     "writedt": "2016-02-08 17:07:38",
     "writerid": "\uce74\ub77c\ube71"
    }]
   }
  }]
 }
}

Comment: this is my json from API and  {{test | json}}

Comment: Here's a demo with your data, notice how I in the service extract data from your json: `.map(res => res.json().hits.hits)` and of course the iteration in the component. Replicate this plunker and you should be good to go :) http://plnkr.co/edit/pYES6Dy1NjJtJaZBMmZF?p=preview

Comment: it works! thank you very much.
but i don't understand 1. why use map in service
2. should use service (@Injectable)
3. How can i build this json interface like 
interface ITest {
  content: string;
  writedt: string;
  writerid: string;
}
i want to use test: ITest[]=[];
instead test: any[]=[];
and thank you for your help again :)

Comment: Well these are quite big questions :) Check the angular.io docs about http for the first two questions https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html. For the third question, you'd need to manipulate and restructure your JSON (in frontend or backend) to be able to type it a interface of the structure you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should access it as below:

```
test[0].A.B[0].C.D[0].writerid
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `test[0].A.B[0].C.D[0].writerid`